# Undefined function when placing in bind event handler

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, bind

I'm tearing my hair out with this. I have a function which I'm able to load on ready, on click, but not when I place it in the bind event handler.

```
// these work
$(document).ready().calHeader();
$(".prevMonth").click().calHeader();

// this doesn't work
$(".prevMonth").bind("click", calHeader);
```

I'm trying to get the last one to work because I don't want the function to run prior to click. The solution from several answered questions says to do it the 3rd way. But I keep getting this error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calHeader is not defined(anonymous function) @ override.js:101
```

Why do the first two work fine but the last one doesn't? What am I missing/not understanding from the explanations? Would really appreciate some direction!

Comment: What does `calHeader` do? Seems strange it works for any element

Comment: Seems like you made it using `$.fn.calHeader = func....` and only really need `$.calHeader = func...` . then call it wherever you want using `$.calHeader()` or `$(".prevMonth").on("click", $.calHeader);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your plugin doesn't seem to be dependent on any selector elements passed to it it would seem it is nothing more than a utlity function

Instead of creating it using `$.fn.calHeader = function` you could use `$.calHeader= function` and do:

```
$(".prevMonth").on("click", $.calHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.calHeader()` works because the `calHeader` function is a property of jQuery objects (i.e. it's a jQuery method defined by the plugin), and the other jQuery methods return a jQuery object so that you can chain methods like this. It's not a variable name, so you can't call it directly or pass it as a function argument.

It's the same reason you can do `$(".prevMonth").click()` but not `click()`.